# What browser features/plugins for opera, IE, firefox, chrome, safari, etc. do you use for browser compatibility testing?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, safari, google-chrome, opera

I use the [Nightly Tester Tools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6543) for Firefox and [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) for IE. What do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web Developer toolbar for Firefox, Visual Studio JIT debugger for IE, and Chrome's Resource Inspector.  We don't use Opera for debugging due to the aforementioned tools, but we do take a look at our stuff to make sure it looks correct in Opera to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

A nice question. I have never think about it before. We test our website with a large range of custom configure browser. This are the browser of the different developers. The  inhomogeneous is program.

Problems we had only with 2 plugins: Adblock and FlashBlock

I would also test NoScript.

Answer (score 0):

Opera has Dragonfly (Tools → Advanced → Developer Tools).

I like [mouse over DOM inspector](http://slayeroffice.com/?c=/content/tools/modi.html) – it's simple, fast and cross-browser.

Answer (score 0):

In Opera

> View > Style

And all those various little selections (such as Outline, Class and Id, etc) have been great help in figuring out the floats and border constraints of DIVs and SPANs, the class and ID names of elements and makes switching back to tweak the code so much faster.

And that shortcut (`CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+U` in v9) to load the current page into the W3C validator is nifty too.